# Django form submit for multiple urls (or) views

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, http-post

Is there any way to use a submited form data to apply all the view,
For example,

I have a form in one page,

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="{% url 'a_view' %}">
   <label for="Region">Region</label>
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Region" type="text" id="Region">
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
```

And have a other form in another page with same form inputs,

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="{% url 'b_view' %}">
   <label for="Region">Region</label>
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Region" type="text" id="Region">
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
```

From this form I get a text for filtering the data for different models,after I have to send to the different view.
what I want to do is,
 when the form is applied,it should apply the form to all the views in my app.

In view.py,

```
def aview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          sbc = MTD.pdobjects.all()
          df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
          filter_list = request.POST.get('regionwiselist', None)
          df=df[df['RGN'].isin(filter_list)]
          df1=pandas.pivot_table(df,index='MKU',columns='Vertical',values=['Sales_Value','Unit_Sales_Price'],aggfunc='sum').replace(numpy.nan,0)
          df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
          dict1=df1.transpose().to_dict()
          col=list(df1.columns)
          context={
                  'MKU_value':dict1,
                  'MKU':col
          }
          return render(request, 'aview.html', context)
    else:
        sbc = MTD.pdobjects.all()
        df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
        df=df[df['RGN'].isin(filter_list)]
        df1=pandas.pivot_table(df,index='MKU',columns='Vertical',values=['Sales_Value','Unit_Sales_Price'],aggfunc='sum').replace(numpy.nan,0)
        df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dict1=df1.transpose().to_dict()
        col=list(df1.columns)
        context={
                'MKU_value':dict1,
                'MKU':col
        }
        return render(request, 'aview.html', context)
def bview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          sbc = MTD.pdobjects.all()
          df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
          filter_list = request.POST.get('regionwiselist', None)
          df=df[df['RGN'].isin(filter_list)]
          df1=pandas.pivot_table(df,index='Customer',columns='Salesman', values=['Sales_Value','Unit_Sales_Price'],aggfunc='sum').replace(numpy.nan,0)
          df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
          dict1=df1.transpose().to_dict()
          col=list(df1.columns)
          context={
                  'MKU_value':dict1,
                  'MKU':col
          }
          return render(request, 'bview.html', context)
    else:
        sbc = MTD.pdobjects.all()
        df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
        df=df[df['RGN'].isin(filter_list)]
        df1=pandas.pivot_table(df,index='Customer',columns='Saleman',values=['Sales_Value','Unit_Sales_Price'],aggfunc='sum').replace(numpy.nan,0)
        df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dict1=df1.transpose().to_dict()
        col=list(df1.columns)
        context={
                'MKU_value':dict1,
                'MKU':col
        }
        return render(request, 'bview.html', context)
```

we don't use forms.py, instead we use pandas dataframe for table to dataframe and filters.

Please help me to sort out,
Thanks.

Comment: More detail in your question would be helpful, but it sounds like you might need to create your own middleware.  I would suggest looking at the first paragraph here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering, and then the following for a quick overview before diving into the detail on that page:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering

Comment: @Dan Swain. Thanks.. But im trying to apply the form  to all the view in my app.. Is there anyway to create a form globally to apply the form to views.

Comment: @Dan Swain.. Yes. I want a middleware for getting input from the user, By that input .. I have to filter the data on all the views..

Comment: You really need to show more of your current code (views.py, forms.py, etc.) in order to be able to have someone answer.

Comment: @DanSwain  i updated the code, Please help me to sort out..

Comment: @DanSwain Is there anyway still cant find the answer